# Zero keypoints detected with BRIEF, BRISK, AKAZE and FREAK

Tags: python, feature-detection, opencv, feature-descriptor

I am trying to do Feature Detection and Description with the **BRIEF**, **BRISK**, **AKAZ**E and **FREAK** Binary Descriptors.

I'm doing a test with a 28x28 image of the **MINIST** visual dataset, as can be seen below:

[image]

I called all methods the following way:

**FAST:**

```
FAST = cv.FastFeatureDetector_create(threshold = 80,
                                     nonmaxSuppression = True)
```

**BRIEF:**

```
BRIEF = cv.xfeatures2d.BriefDescriptorExtractor_create(bytes = 16,
                                                       use_orientation = False)
```

**BRISK:**

```
BRISK = cv.BRISK_create(thresh = 30,
                        octaves = 0,
                        patternScale = 1.0)
```

**AKAZE:**

```
AKAZE = cv.AKAZE_create(descriptor_type = cv.AKAZE_DESCRIPTOR_MLDB,
                        descriptor_size = 0,
                        descriptor_channels = 3,
                        threshold = 0.001,
                        nOctaves = 4,
                        nOctaveLayers = 4,
                        diffusivity = cv.KAZE_DIFF_PM_G2)
```

**FREAK:**

```
FREAK = cv.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create(orientationNormalized = True,
                                    scaleNormalized = True,
                                    patternScale = 22.0,
                                    nOctaves = 4)
```

**NOTE 1:** I used the Descriptors **BRIEF** and **FREAK** with the **FAST** Detector.

I finded the Keypoints and compute the Descriptors, as bellow:

```
keypoints = FAST.detect(image, None)
keypoints, descriptors = BRIEF.compute(image, keypoints)
```

Note that in this example I'm trying to find the Keyponts and compute the **BRIEF** Descriptors, but for **ALL** the Descriptors described above, I get the following output:

```
print("Keyponts:", keypoints, "\n")

print("Descriptors:", descriptors, "\n")

Keyponts: [] 

Descriptors: None
```

**NOTE 2:** I used the same parameters presented with any other 640x546 size image and I was able to find Keypoints and compute the Descriptors. The problem is that I'm doing a search where I'll need to use the **MINIST** visual dataset.

**NOTE 3:** With other Descriptors such as **SIFT**, **SURF**, **KAZE** and **ORB** I was able to find Keyponts and compute Descriptors for that same visual dataset.

I have changed the parameters of **ALL** the Descriptors several times, but unfortunately I can't find Keypoints and compute Descriptors with them in the visual dataset **MNIST**. I would like to know if there is a right way to choose these parameters or if there is something I can do.

I believe there is a problem in finding Keypoints and computer Descriptors with these Descriptors in small images **(?)** of size 28x28 **(?)**.

I'm using **Python 3.6** and **OpenCV 4.1** (with **opencv_contrib** modules).

Comment: Usually descriptors work in a neighborhood something like 32x32... So yes, your images are too small

Comment: BRIEF, BRISK and FREAK works in a 31x31 neighborhood, as well as ORB. However, ORB Descriptor worked perfectly with the MNIST visual dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause:

`MNIST` images are 28x28 pixels, as described in the question.

To find keypoints and compute descriptors, remarkable descriptors like `SIFT` and `SURF` can obtain great results in tinier patches, still, many descriptors (e.g. `ORB`) obtain great results in a 32x32 patch.

It was not possible to obtain results on `MNIST` using the descriptors `BRIEF`, `BRISK`, `AKAZE`, and `FREAK`, since `MNIST` has small images.

### Solution:

To avoid the return of keypoints without descriptors, `BRIEF`, `BRISK`, `AKAZE`, and `FREAK` remove the keypoints. With this, it is possible to observe that these descriptors do not fit properly in images present in the `MNIST` dataset.

### Other Tests:

However, with the descriptors `BRIEF`, `BRISK`, `AKAZE`, and `FREAK`, it was possible to obtain results (using the same parameters presented in the question) with any other image that has grander patches (In this experiment 640x546 patch).

`BRIEF`:

[image]

`BRISK`:

[image]

`AKAZE`:

[image]

`FREAK`:

[image]

With this, it is possible to observe that the image with a size of 640x546 pixels has somewhat more significant features.

I hope this answer helps others who have this same question.

To learn more about Detection and Description techniques, I recommend the following repository on GitHub:

- https://github.com/whoisraibolt/Feature-Detection-and-Description